# vlookup work in awk on linux

Tags: text-processing, awk, join

Hi I have two files containing data:
file1:

```
4,abc
3,xyz
5,fut
6,gfd
```

file2:

```
gfd,2.3
xyz,4.5
abc,6.7
fut,3.2
```

i wish to create a file3 as output file using linux scripting commands:

```
4,6.7
3,4.5
5,3.2
6,2.3
```

how do I use FR=NFR etc. awk scripting to do this

Answer (score 1):

With `join`:

```
join -t, -1 2 -2 1 -o 1.1,2.2 <(sort -t, -k2 file1) <(sort -t, -k1 file2)
```

- `-t,` set delimiter to `,`.
- `-1 2` the first files join field is the second one.
- `-2 1` the second files join field is the first one.
- `-o 1.1,2.2` the output format
- `<(sort ...)` join need input files, which are sorted on the join field.

Answer (score 0):

With `awk`:

**script.awk:**

```
FNR==NR{
    var[$2]=$1
}
FNR!=NR{
    print(var[$1]","$2)
}
```

Call the script with

```
awk -F, -f script.awk file1 file2
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar awk one liner:

```
awk -F"," 'FNR==NR{var[$2]=$1;next;}{print var[$1]FS$2}'  file1 file2
```

Output:

```
$ awk -F"," 'FNR==NR{var[$2]=$1;next;}{print var[$1]FS$2}'  file1.txt file2.txt
6,2.3
3,4.5
4,6.7
5,3.2
```